# Delete meshgrid points between a bounding box points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to delete points of a meshgrid that comes inside the bounding box of blocks (block 1 and 2 in the code). My Code is:

```
x_max, x_min, y_max, y_min = 156.0, 141.0, 96.0, 80.0
offset = 5
stepSize = 0.2
x = np.arange(x_min-offset, x_max+offset, stepSize)
y = np.arange(y_min-offset, y_max+offset, stepSize)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
#bounding box (and pints inside) that I want to remove for mesh
block1 = [(139.78, 86.4), (142.6, 86.4), (142.6, 88.0), (139.78, 88.0)]
block2 = [(154.8, 87.2), (157.6, 87.2), (157.6, 88.8), (154.8, 88.8)]
```

As per one of the answer, I could generate the required result if I have only one block to be removed from the mesh. If I have multiple blocks then it won't work. What could be the optimized way to remove multiple blocks from mesh grid. The final figure should look like this:
[Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOFf8.png)

Edit: Improved questions and edited code.

Comment: `xv` and `yv` are 2d arrays.  You can't 'delete' single elements from arrays like that and retain the 2d layout.  You could `ravel` them, and then delete elements from the resulting 1d arrays (or rather make new arrays omitting selected elements).

Comment: Define a small mesh, e.g. (10,10) with integer values, and show us what a modified mesh would look like.  Forget about efficiency for now.  You/we need to know clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have further improved the question to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: A mesh like that can't represented by 2d arrays like `xv`.  For a start I'd reshape them into `grid=np.column_stack((xv.ravel(), yv.ravel()))`, shape `(16250, 2)`.  And then figure out which pairs are in the excluded blocks, and then using boolean masking or advanced indexing, make a new array without the blocks.  No fancy short cuts that I'm aware of.  Just explore the grid till you find a reasonable way of identifying the exclude vs keep points.

Comment: Another idea is to play with `maskedArrays`, masking the holes, either in `xv` etc or in a 0/1 mask of the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out based on the explanation of @hpaulj (I cannot up-vote his suggestions as well probably due to low points). I can append blocks in allBlocks array and then run a loop over allBlocks an simultaneous disabling the points in mesh. Here is my solution:

```
x_new = np.copy(xv)
y_new = np.copy(yv)

ori_x = xv[0][0]
ori_y = yv[0][0]

for block in allBlocks:

    block_xmin = np.min((block[0][0], block[1][0]))
    block_xmax = np.max((block[0][0], block[1][0]))
    block_ymin = np.min((block[0][1], block[1][1]))
    block_ymax = np.max((block[0][1], block[3][1]))

    rx_min, rx_max = int((block_xmin-ori_x)/stepSize), int((block_xmax-ori_x)/stepSize)
    ry_min, ry_max = int((block_ymin-ori_y)/stepSize), int((block_ymax-ori_y)/stepSize)
    for i in range(rx_min,rx_max+1):
        for j in range(ry_min,ry_max+1):
            x_new[j][i] = np.nan
    for i in range(ry_min,ry_max+1):
        for j in range(rx_min,rx_max+1):
            y_new[i][j] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply redefine your x and y around your block:

```
block_xmin = np.min(block[:,0])
block_xmax = np.max(block[:,0])
block_ymin = np.min(block[:,1])
block_ymax = np.max(block[:,1])

X = np.hstack((np.arange(x_min-offset, block_xmin, stepSize), np.arange(block_xmax, x_max+offset, stepSize)))
Y = np.hstack((np.arange(y_min-offset, block_ymin, stepSize), np.arange(block_ymax, y_max+offset, stepSize)))

XV, YV = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I believe it will remove all the points from block_xmin to block_xmax and block_ymin to block_ymax i.e. not only the box but the range of points in the define min and max range. But I can modifiy it to add those points again through hstack option.

Comment: Yes I think I follow what you mean.  My answer was for illustration purposes and I'm sure it can be further refined.